# Algorithm to compute $n^{\log k}$ in $O(\log\log k)$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I was given this exercise and I think I have to use a variation of Gauss repeated squaring, but I can not figure out how to produce $\log\log k$ in steps, like when you divide $k$ by $2$ to compute $\log k$ in steps. Any ideas?

Comment: Just use repeated squaring.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to use *repeated squaring*. Compute $n,n^2,n^4,\ldots n^{\log k}$. To compute $n^{2^i}$ use the fact that $n^{2^i} = n^{2^{i-1}} n^{2^{i-1}}$. Note that the answer of $n^{2^{i-1}}$ will be known in the $i$th iteration.

Comment: do you mean ${n^{log{k}}}$? And if so, how do I know when to stop (i.e. the value of ${logk}$)?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate $n^m$ in O (log m) multiplications. You find m = log(k) and use that.

There are two problems with this: One is doing a multiplication of possibly large numbers in constant time. The other is calculating log k in O(log log k). If I write down k in base two, you’d have to count the digits of k which takes O(log k).